# avoid rows with null value from the result

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I got the result while executing my query as:

```
state city  user_count   restaurant_count   order_count
a      b      0            0                 5
a      c      2            0                 0 
a      d      0            0                 0
```

and my query is :

```
SELECT `eat_state_locale`.`state`, `eat_city_locale`.`city`, `eat_city_locale`.`location`, `eat_city`.`city_id`, count(distinct eat_user.user_id) as user_count, count(distinct eat_delivery.restaurant_id) as restaurant_count, count(distinct eat_order.order_id) as order_count FROM (`eat_state`) JOIN `eat_state_locale` ON `eat_state_locale`.`state_id`=`eat_state`.`state_id` JOIN `eat_city` ON `eat_state`.`state_id`=`eat_city`.`state_id` JOIN `eat_city_locale` ON `eat_city_locale`.`city_id`=`eat_city`.`city_id` LEFT JOIN `eat_user` ON `eat_user`.`city_id`=`eat_city`.`city_id` LEFT JOIN `eat_delivery` ON `eat_delivery`.`delivery_city_id`=`eat_city`.`city_id` LEFT JOIN `eat_order` ON `eat_order`.`delivery_city_id`=`eat_city`.`city_id` LEFT JOIN `eat_printer` ON `eat_printer`.`order_id`=`eat_order`.`order_id` WHERE `eat_state_locale`.`language_id` = 1 AND `eat_city_locale`.`language_id` = 1 GROUP BY `eat_city`.`city_id` ORDER BY `eat_state`.`state_id` asc
```

here i need to get the result like (after avoiding the null values as:)

```
state city  user_count   restaurant_count   order_count
a      b      0            0                 5
a      c      2            0                 0
```

how will I get such result?Here no issue in the counted result..I need to avoid the null result

Comment: Could you make the SQL readable by putting line breaks etc in and using SO's formatting although the latter is not sufficient

Comment: next time please format your code properly

Comment: the `COUNT` function never returns `NULL` (well, it counts), it can return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
SELECT 
   blah
HAVING
   user_count > 0 AND
   restaurant_count > 0 
   AND order_count > 0;
```

Comment: sorry this didn't work. there is no issue with the counted result. issue is with the null data,

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE .... AND ( user_count != 0 OR restaurant_count != 0 OR  order_count  != 0 )
```

If that doesn't work try this:

```
GROUP BY .... HAVING user_count > 0 OR restaurant_count > 0 OR  order_count  > 0
```

Answer (score -1):

try in where condition

```
AND your_field IS NOT NULL
```